# The annihilators in dual operator algebras.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is well known that in every von Neumann algebra $\mathcal{M}$,  the left  annihilator of a given subset $S\subseteq \mathcal{M}$ is in the form $\mathcal{M}p$ for some projection $p$ in $\mathcal{M}$.

By a  dual operator algebra $\mathcal{A}$, we mean a WOT-closed subalgebra of operators on some Hilbert space $H$.

Q. Does there exist any similar characterization of the left annihilators in dual operator algebras?

Comment: Hi. I saw that you didn't accept any (recent) answers on your questions. Is there a reason for this? I spend some time writing this answer and an upvote/accept lets me know that I helped you/that my answer is correct. On the other hand, accepting answers earns you a little reputation as well, so it looks like a win-win to me :)

Comment: @ QuantumSpace  Sorry, I had forgotten to do it, many thanks for your replay and reminder.

Comment: Could you please unaccept the answer below? It contains a mistake and I want to delete it.

Comment: @AliBagheri I know this question is rather open-ended, but if you want the left annihilator to be of the form $\mathcal A e$ for an idempotent $e$, you could try and see if this holds for simple examples like the algebra of upper triangular matrices. It is not true for left ideals (see my comments under QuantumSpace's answer), so I would be surprised if it's true for left annihilators, but I don't see an immediate counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contained an answer with a mistake, but I can't delete because the OP does not unaccept the question.

Comment: This proof is incorrect. You assert that $x^\ast x\in \mathscr{L}$, but in general, $x^\ast$ does not even belong to $\mathscr{M}$. In fact, matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}0&a\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ form an ideal in the space of all upper triangular matrices that is not of the form $\mathscr{M}e$ for a projection $e\in\mathscr{M}$.

Comment: @MaoWao Yes you are right. Thanks for pointing this out! Guess I'm too used to working with involutive algebras... I suggest you write an answer presenting your counterexample so that the OP can accept your answer and I can delete mine :)

Comment: But the ideal from my comment is not a left annihilator, so that's not a counterexample to the original question.

Comment: @MaoWao Hm alright then. I'll just ask that the OP removes the accept from this answer so I can delete it.